# Disable bootstrap scroll spy when on mobile

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, scrollspy

I'm in a freaky situation.

How can I prevent bootstrap scroll-spy from "spying" using javascript ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow